# Imputing fractions using arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, fractions

My program asks the user for a numerator and then a denominator right after (If option 1 is chosen). I am pretty sure i got that part correct.I can not seem to figure out how to display the fraction(s) though when I hit option 2.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct fraction
{
int numerator, denom;
} fraction; //defined the fraction.

int main()
{//start of program 

int z = 0;
int y = 0;

 while (1) 
    { //start of while loop 
    int choice;
    printf("\nPress 1 to enter a fraction\n"); 
    printf("Press 2 to view the entered fraction\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    fraction arrFraction[100];

    arrFraction[0].numerator = 0;
    arrFraction[0].denom = 0;

    if (choice == 1) // first option (enter numerator and then denom after)
    {
        printf("Enter the fraction\n");
        scanf("%d", &arrFraction[y].numerator);
        scanf("%d", &arrFraction[z].denom);
     y++    
     z++;

    }// end of first if statement(to enter the fraction)

    if (choice == 2) //to view the entered fractions.
    {
        printf("\n-----------------------------");

        for (int m = 0; m < z; m++)
        {
            printf("  %d / %d \n", arrFraction[y].numerator/arrFraction[z].denom);
        }
        printf("\n\n-----------------------------");
    } // end of second if statement (to view the fraction entered earlier)
      } // end of while loop

system("pause");
return(0);

}
```

Comment: ` printf("  %d / %d \n", arrFraction[y].numerator,arrFraction[z].denom);`

Comment: Was [previously asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312021/entering-and-storing-fractions-in-c-using-arrays-strings) by the OP only 2 hours ago. It still used two variables to index the same array element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `fraction arrFraction[100];` out of `while` loop, otherwise, every iteration, there will be a new array.

That said,

```
 printf("  %d / %d \n", arrFraction[y].numerator/arrFraction[z].denom);
```

is wrong, you're supplying two format specifiers but one argument. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your compiler should have warned you.

I believe, what you want instead is

```
 printf("  %d / %d \n", arrFraction[y].numerator, arrFraction[z].denom);
```

---

That said, I'm not very convinced with the overall logic. Why do you seem to need an array of `100` elements? If you're only interested in *previous* record (not records), use only a simple variable, not an array. Besides, you don;t need to have two separate index/ counters anyway. A single index will be able to manage the inputs in much concise and robust way.

Comment: I moved the arrFraction out of the while loop and tried used that printf() statement however it did not work?

Comment: I need it in array because later i will sort the fractions in order form smallest to biggest.